# Swift: unable to set commands in NSSpeechRecognizer

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, speech-recognition

I have a problem with setCommands. I'm not able to set the commands for setCommands in my project. In viewDidLoad I tried SR.setCommands = commands but i get an error saying "'NSSpeechRecognizer' does not have a member named 'setCommands'" Any help with that?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var Label: NSTextField!

var SR:NSSpeechRecognizer = NSSpeechRecognizer()
var commands: [AnyObject]? = ["word","sad","happy"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SR.setCommands = commands //Error
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}

@IBAction func Listen(sender: AnyObject) {
    SR.startListening(); print("listening")
}

func speechRecognizer(sender: NSSpeechRecognizer,
    didRecognizeCommand command: AnyObject?){

        if (command as String == "word")
        {
            println("Hello")
        }
        else
        {
            println("NotWord")
        }

    }

@IBAction func Stop(sender: AnyObject) {
    SR.stopListening()
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SR.commands = commands
```

You're mixing dot-notation with old Obj-C-style setters.

You also can use `let` for your speech recognizer, and you don't need to state either's type; Swift will infer it:

```
let SR = NSSpeechRecognizer()
var commands = ["word","sad","happy"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But how do I compare the spoken with my commands, because now my if statement seems to do nothing.